# How to install Gregorio package on Ubuntu with TeXLive installed?

Tags: installing, texlive, gregorio

Does anyone here have experience installing the [gregorio](http://home.gna.org/gregorio/) packages to work in Ubuntu using the non-repo TeXLive?

Gregorio isn't packaged on CTAN as far as I could tell, and I don't know enough to be able to figure out how to make the TeXLive install, see the various fonts and whatnot that are required.

Comment: gregorio isn't on ctan because its author never submitted it.  (its predecessor sat on ftp.ac.uk:/incoming for a while, but he asked me to remove it.)  as a musician i find this rather sad, but we have to comply with the author's requests.

Answer (score 3):

After looking into install.py, it seems that everything is at its place. Check that in the definition of TexliveDirs, at the beginning of the file, there is a pointer to the "texmf-local" directory.

You find the right value by saying, at the command line

```
kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL
```

If the answer is not in that definition, put it there. For example, on
Mac OS X there's not the right one. :(

Run the installation with suitable privileges:

```
sudo make install
sudo ./install.py
```

are the correct way to put things in the right places (in the instructions the lines are those preceded by `#`).

I'll give a try on a Ubuntu machine.

## ***Some news***

The installation of the fonts has been successful on Ubuntu 11.04; the steps were as follows

1) edit install.py in such a way that the local directory name is present; for my case, where TeX Live 2010 is the TeX distribution, it's just to have

```
TexliveDirs=['/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local']
```

in the first lines of the file, as the command `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL` answers `/usr/local/texlive/2010/../texmf-local`

2) run `./install.py` but specifying the path for the necessary binaries; I usually create a soft link `/opt/texbin` to the binaries, so

```
PATH=/opt/texbin:${PATH} ./install.py
```

did the job.

If the TeX distribution is the TeX Live 2009/Ubuntu no adjustment should be necessary.