# Texlive and Gregorio Manual Font Installation

Tags: fonts, texlive, gregorio

Here I am again trying to get [Gregorio](http://home.gna.org/gregorio/) working.  I discovered that the Gregorio installation failed to install its fonts, so I am trying to install them manually.

When I run Gregorio, I get this output:

```
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
checksum mismatch in font ptmrc8t.vf ignored
checksum mismatch in font greciliae.ofm.vf ignored
checksum mismatch in font ptmrc8t.vf ignored
checksum mismatch in font ptmbc8t.vf ignored
checksum mismatch in font ptmri8t.vf ignored  (./PopulusSion.tex
Module luatexbase-mcb info: inserting 'gregoriotex.callback'
(luatexbase-mcb)            at position 1 in 'post_linebreak_filter'

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--403

Module luatexbase-mcb info: removing 'gregoriotex.callback'
(luatexbase-mcb)            from 'post_linebreak_filter'
) [1{c:/Users/username/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.m
ap}] (./main-lualatex.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
 38653 words of node memory still in use:
   1248 hlist, 209 vlist, 835 rule, 2074 glue, 833 kern, 10 penalty, 414 glyph,
 874 attribute, 91 glue_spec, 441 attribute_list, 1 write, 416 pdf_colorstack n
odes
   avail lists: 2:1334,3:414,4:245,5:512,6:507,7:48,9:277,10:12
 <c:/Users/username/.texlive2012/texmf-var/fonts/pk/modeless/gregoriotex/greci
liae/greciliae-3.1556pk
!LuaTeX error (file greciliae-3): unexpected eof in pk file
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

So, I decided to try to "enable" the fonts with this (none of these work, although I've seen all three usages in the documentation):

```
    updmap-sys --enable map grecilia.map
or
    updmap --enable map grecilia.map
or
    updmap --enable map=gregilia.map
```

Any of those commands gets me this output:

```
c:\texlive\gregorio\fonts>updmap-sys --enable map grecilia.map
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  c:/texlive/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  c:/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  c:/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap: invalid mapType map at c:/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/tetex/updmap.pl line 1396.
C:\texlive\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:591: command failed with exit code 2:
perl.exe c:/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/tetex/updmap.pl --enable map grecilia.map
```

Now, I've placed the font files in their appropriate folders in `c:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\` - including the map files in the subdirectory there at `map\dvips\gregoriotex`

I've ran `texhash` to no avail.

When I run `updmap` I don't see that it scans the directory at `c:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts`

How can I get it to scan that directory?

What can I do to get past this?

Comment: My recommendation: Do _additionally_ download the `gregorio-2.0.tar.gz`, extract everything into a temporary folder and install TeX style and font files according to [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88423/manual-font-installation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay! After a day of hacking and slashing, I figured it out:
(a note here - I chose `c:\texlive` as my root directory.  The default is `c:\texlive\2012\` - the Windows installer failed both ways, however, so it doesn't matter what directory you install everything into).  After texlive was installed, I installed (via the installer) Gregorio into `c:\texlive\gregorio\`.

Now, the installer for Gregorio comes with a single directory full of the tex fonts, but they have no arrangement, they are all lumped together in a single folder.  There is an installation script called `install.py` but either the installer doesn't use it or for some reason it doesn't work right.

First, you have to [copy Gregorio's tex files to their proper place](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/103342), as the installer fails to do this as well.  So, find the directory `c:\texlive\gregorio\tex\` and copy it to `c:\texlive\tedmf-local\tex\latex\`.  You can't skip this step.

I created a simple text file named `updmap.cfg` in `c:\texlive\texmf-local\web2c\`
and put in it the following code (cyphered from Gregorio's fonts folder `install.py`):

```
# $Id: updmap.cfg 26891 2012-06-10 22:41:49Z karl $
# updmap.cfg for TEXMFLOCAL - updmap options.
#Gregoriotex Config
MixedMap greciliae.map
MixedMap gregorio.map
MixedMap parmesan.map
```

then I ran this command (again, cyphered from install.py):

```
mktexlsr c:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts
texhash
updmap
```

One more thing:  Find `c:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\gregoriotex.tex`, (which you should have copied over already) and open it in a text editor.  Now find `\luatexUseModule` and `\luaUseModule` and replace both instances with `\RequireLuaModule`.  It won't work if you don't do this.

And it works!!!!!
I've got chant notes!!!
(I hope nobody else has to do it this way!)

[image: Kyrie XVIII generated by Gregorio]

[UPDATE]

Gregorio has been updated to version 2.3 as of June 2013, and just about all of these installation issues have been corrected. Here is a link to the download repository: http://download.gna.org/gregorio/releases/

[UPDATE]

Gregorio has been updated to version 2.4.2 as of March 2015, and so again, most of this is obsolete.  However, [here is a tidbit about adding/updating your own font files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232921/updating-your-own-font).

Comment: Glad it worked. Font installation is (IMO) difficult for "ordinary" users. It has bitten me a few times and I always need a manual when installing fonts. BTW with the `fontspec` package, there's no need to install OpenType fonts the TeX way. You can use them out of the box but you have to use XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: @BGM Thanks for posting the answer. If you have time can you extend the post a bit with some more explanations. From the website a cursory look indicates is run on Omega test, but from what I gather is not. Also nice if you add an image of `kyrie eleyson`:)

Comment: @Speravir - Well, I really don't know anything at all about python, tex, lua, texlua, or tex-anything!  I didn't follow any guide other than outguessing (that is, I didn't follow the paths exactly as they were coded) what was written in the `install.py` script that came with Gregorio.

Comment: I added one more note about a modification necessary in the gregoriotex.tex file.  I learned that tidbit from a nice fellow (T.G.) on the gregorio-users list.  Gregorio won't work if you don't make those edits.

Comment: Oh, if you are on this list, try to ask concerning bug fix(es). In my eyes it would also be better for the developers to provide at least the (La)TeX part in a packed file in TDS structure. This could extracted upon installation, as well.

Comment: And interesting, if you intend to file some bugs: [egreg’s answer to “How to install Gregorio package on Ubuntu with TeXLive installed?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14384/9237).