# Updating Your Own Font

Tags: fonts, luatex, texlive, windows

In my scenario I am using my own custom font.  It is an OpenType font - not a tex-packaged one either, just one I've made in FontCreator (Windows 7).
Now, I want to use this font with `lualatex`, so I put a copy of `myfont.otf` here
`C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\fonts\truetype\public` and it gets picked up.

My problem:
If I update `myfont.otf` and replace the copy in that folder with a new one, it doesn't get used because `lualatex` is using the one in its cache, as is reflected in this log entry:

```
luaotfload | load: auto-selecting default features for script: dflt(load luc: C:/texlive/2013/texmf-var/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/myfont.luc)
```

Now, so far the only way I have found to get my font used (after I've replaced it) is to:

1. Delete `lualatex`'s cache directories at `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-var\luatex-cache\`, `%USERPROFILE%\.texlive2013\texmf-var` and `C:\texlive\texmf-var\lualatex-cache`
2. Then run `texhash`
3. Then run `updmap`

When I compile the next tex file, it rebuilds the cache using the new font:

```
luaotfload | resolve: font family='priory', subfamily='regular' found: c:/texliv
e/2013/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/myfont.otf(save: C:/texlive/2013/texmf-v
ar/luatex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/myfont.lua)(save: C:/texlive/2013/texmf-var/lu
atex-cache/generic/fonts/otf/myfont.luc)
```

Is there a better way to do this?  Can I rebuild the font cache without having to manually delete directories?

Comment: The luc doesn't contain the font, only informations about metrics etc. And you don't need to run texhash or updmap. Imho you can delete the cache with `luaotfload-tool --cache=erase` or `luaotfload-tool --cache=purge` (no idea what is the difference).

Comment: Not sure what purge does, but erase does erase the files in the cache folder at `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-var\luatex-cache\generic\fonts\otf`

Comment: *Not sure what purge does* -- Recommended reading: ``man 1 luaotfload-tool``; from that man page: “1. purge -> delete Lua files from cache; 2. erase -> delete Lua and Luc files from cache;”.

Comment: Putting personal things in `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-dist\fonts\truetype\public` is not a good idea. Use `C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\truetype\<fontname>` creating the needed directories if not existent; `<fontname>` stands for an arbitrary string, say `myfont` if your font is `myfont.ttf`. Of course, if the font is OTF, use `opentype` instead of `truetype`.

Comment: egreg - You are right.  I moved things to the texmf-local and it works perfectly.

Comment: @phg: we poor windows users can't use `man`. In texlive I can find a pdf-file with `texdoc luaotfload-tool`, in miktex I couldn't find nothing with `texdoc`, and with a file search in the doc folder only a `luaotfload-tool.1`.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: The man page is generated from a [human readable source](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/blob/master/doc/luaotfload-tool.rst). The installed version of that file (matching your distribution’s Luaotfload package) can be read like so: ``less $(kpsewhich --format=source luaotfload-tool.rst)`` -- of course substituting the Windows equivalent of a pager for ``less`` and adapting the command substitution to the shell you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was manually deleting this directory: `C:\texlive\2013\texmf-var\luatex-cache\`

This same procedure is accomplished with the commandline (thanks Ulrik):

```
luaotfload-tool --cache=erase
```

Then, if your font name is different (or you added a new one), you need to do this:

```
texhash
```

However, the commenters to my question are right.  It is better not to use a tex system folder.  In Windows it is funny to call it a system folder since it only matters to tex.  BUT I moved my fonts to `C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\truetype\public`  and ran those commands and everything worked like it should.  I can see from the compilation log that the fonts were pulled from the new location.

So this tex user directory is better, but the commands are the same:

```
luaotfload-tool --cache=erase
texhash
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21926/discussion-between-bgm-and-cfr).

Comment: Why don't you use `opentype` rather than `truetype`?

Comment: It doesn't matter - the extensions `.ttf` and `.otf` are interchangeable - they are both opentype beneath the scenes.  However, it is commong practice that if you add opentype layout features that you use the `.otf` extension to show it.  Read this: http://forum.high-logic.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1619